# My Google Cloud VM, Cant SSH and all hosted websites on GCP Showing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

Need Help with My Google Cloud VM, Cant SSH into my VM , The OS used is Ubuntu 18. and all hosted websites on GCP Showing 500 Internal Server Error. done everything yet no progress.

Comment: try to show us what you have tried,

Comment: I manually generated an SSH Key, and tried accessing my VM through Cloud Shell since i couldn't SSH Directly, but i keep getting permission denied, am using the Vesta Cpanel which runs under my Ubuntu Setup, i also cant login either, also tried using Putty to login with my private Key, it still rejected me gaining access

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl How do you mean my question is off topic?

Comment: Please follow the link in my comment, to learn, what questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow. SO is about programming, not server/cloud management.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)? If yes, please show us what you have tried with commands and outputs.